# NAnt using MSBuild

Tags: nant, msbuild-4.0

I am using NAnt to build an asp.net mvc 3 project that contains EXT JS. After the code successfully compiles, msbuild attempts to copy the files into the following sub folder "_PublishedWebsites". Unfortunately the build fails and I get the following error:

```
[msbuild] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(177,5): 
error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "Scripts\Foobar\extjs\resources\css\ext-all-gray.css" to "build\_PublishedWebsites\Foobar.WebUI\Scripts\Foobar\extjs\resources\css\ext-all-gray.css".
Could not find a part of the path 'Scripts\Foobar\extjs\resources\css\ext-all-gray.css'. [C:\Work\Projects\Foobar\Src\Foobar.WebUI\Foobar.WebUI.csproj]
```

The files are in the location but the error seems to occur when files have "-" in the name. To confirm this I excluded the files that were causing the build to fail and what do you know, the build works.Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is about output location not input files, I guess. IMO your part of the output path "Scripts\Foobar\extjs\resources\css\" does not exist. Let's say if "css" folder is missing. Do you have some other .css files without '-' chars in resources\css folder? Are they  deployed correctly?